# How can I use 'phpMyAdmin' WITHOUT having to add script-src 'unsafe-inline' to my Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, apache, phpmyadmin, debian, content-security-policy

Just before I begin; the pertinent information:

I am running Apache2 with php7.3 on Debian Buster.

I have been going through server security procedures today and finally thought I was done when my website - and the javascript - worked without me having to comprimise the CSP.

Then I wanted to access phpmyadmin and all I got was a logo.

Here is the contents of my IFmodule

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#
Header set Content-Security-Policy "base-uri 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; form-action 'self'; default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' blob:; img-src 'self' data: blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self';" "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#text\/(html|javascript)|application\/pdf|xml#i"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know how I can run phpmyadmin without having to compromise security?

Thanks :)

Comment: I love how I'm now finding this question in my ongoing trawl on google :P

Comment: Maybe you could report this at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues